# Having a hard time getting Rabbitmq Server started and wonder why keep getting this Error init:do_boot/3 line 817

Tags: python, django-models, rabbitmq

I keep getting this error when I start Rabbitmq and wonder what's wrong?

```
BOOT FAILED
===========

Error description:
    init:do_boot/3 line 817
    init:start_em/1 line 1109
    rabbit:start_it/1 line 474
    rabbit:broker_start/1 line 350
    rabbit:start_loaded_apps/2 line 600
    app_utils:manage_applications/6 line 126
    lists:foldl/3 line 1263
    rabbit:'-handle_app_error/1-fun-0-'/3 line 723
throw:{could_not_start,ra,
       {ra,
        {{shutdown,
          {failed_to_start_child,ra_system_sup,
           {shutdown,
            {failed_to_start_child,ra_log_sup,
             {shutdown,
              {failed_to_start_child,ra_log_wal_sup,
               {shutdown,
                {failed_to_start_child,ra_log_wal,
                 {{case_clause,{ok,<<0,0,0,0,0>>}},
                  [{ra_log_wal,open_existing,1,
                    [{file,"src/ra_log_wal.erl"},{line,646}]},
                   {ra_log_wal,'-recover_wal/2-lc$^0/1-0-',1,
                    [{file,"src/ra_log_wal.erl"},{line,265}]},
                   {ra_log_wal,recover_wal,2,
                    [{file,"src/ra_log_wal.erl"},{line,268}]},
                   {ra_log_wal,init,1,
                    [{file,"src/ra_log_wal.erl"},{line,214}]},
                   {gen_batch_server,init_it,6,
                    [{file,"src/gen_batch_server.erl"},{line,133}]},
                   {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,
                    [{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,249}]}]}}}}}}}}},
         {ra_app,start,[normal,[]]}}}}
Log file(s) (may contain more information):
   C:/Users/AIMLExpert/AppData/Roaming/RabbitMQ/log/rabbit@DESKTOP-N0Q3S7C.log
   C:/Users/AIMLExpert/AppData/Roaming/RabbitMQ/log/rabbit@DESKTOP-N0Q3S7C_upgrade.log

{"init terminating in do_boot",{could_not_start,ra,{ra,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,ra_system_sup,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,ra_log_sup,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,ra_log_wal_sup,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,ra_log_wal,{{case_clause,{ok,<<0,0,0,0,0>>}},[{ra_log_wal,open_existing,1,[{file,"src/ra_log_wal.erl"},{line,646}]},{ra_log_wal,'-recover_wal/2-lc$^0/1-0-',1,[{file,"src/ra_log_wal.erl"},{line,265}]},{ra_log_wal,recover_wal,2,[{file,"src/ra_log_wal.erl"},{line,268}]},{ra_log_wal,init,1,[{file,"src/ra_log_wal.erl"},{line,214}]},{gen_batch_server,init_it,6,[{file,"src/gen_batch_server.erl"},{line,133}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,249}]}]}}}}}}}}},{ra_app,start,[normal,[]]}}}}}
init terminating in do_boot ({could_not_start,ra,{ra,{{shutdown,{_}},{ra_app,start,[_]}}}})

Crash dump is being written to: C:\Users\AIMLExpert\AppData\Roaming\RabbitMQ\log\erl_crash.dump...done
```

whats causing this Error? I have tried restarting the command line but am still getting the error.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had the same issue on Arch Linux due to a crash dump. It was saying in the logs that it had problem with reverting a WAL file that was 0 bytes in size.
After removing the WAL file the service started.
Locate the WAL in /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia with 
`find /var/lib/rabbitmq/ -name "*.wal"` 
and remove it. 
Restart the service afterwards.

Comment: I was able to get the problem solved by running the command  Rabbitmq-server restart and I also got celery to connect to the server by running the command Celery -A app_name worker --loglevel=info. so everything is working well.

Comment: I was strugging with this issue for 3 days. It worked for MAC OS as well.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the problem solved by running the command Rabbitmq-server restart and I also got celery to connect to the server by running the command Celery -A app_name worker --loglevel=info. so everything is working well.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a Windows machine, the .wal file you need to delete is located in `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\RabbitMQ\db\rabbit@computername-mnesia\quorum\rabbit@computername`